# Add multiple text in textField without rewriting old entries?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

I want to add multiple text value in text field. The values comes from different different views. But when i go to next view and select some text value from second view and come to first view the value replaces the old value of text field. How can i maintain the old textfield value with new one and show both values in same textfield.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think ur changing value in the viewwillappear of the firstview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you move to next page then store the textfield value to a string variable and when you come back append the new text to previous one and set it to textfield

in first view .h

NSString *textfieldValue;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *textfieldValue;

in first view .m file

@ synthesize textfieldValue;

Comment: first you have a value in textfield then when you move to second view store it in a NSMutableString and in second view appen that string by which you want and when you go back then in viewWillAppear set that string to your textfield

Comment: Hello Saadnib, how can i access the same NSMutableString in two clacces.

Comment: i have updated my answer look at there. Now you can access it as a property of first view.

Comment: Thanks Saadnib, I have do it with the help of you guys.

Answer (score 1):

i would try something like this , make nsmutable string and textfield value will be nsmutable string , so when user goes to other view just append in string and always show value in textfield from mutable string

good luck

Comment: Hello Kshitiz, MAy you make your answer more specific and clear. I m new in iPhone. Thanks

Comment: i mean to say is declare NSMutableString as your instant variable, and displayText=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",urMutableString] now when you go to another view [urMutableString stringByAppendingString:@"another view"] just modify urMutableString when you go to another view

Comment: but how will i access the same nsmutablestring in two different views ?

Comment: use id delegate variable in you second view and set id as your current view then it can be assessed from your second view , it is called delegate pattern.

Comment: Thanks Kshitiz. I will study more on delegate pattern. I have perform it.

Answer (score 0):

In the controller owning the first view add a NSString *displayedText variable.
When changing the text, do 
`[displayedText stringByAppendingString:@"secont_text"];
]`